# Using a variable to get resource field

Tags: java, android-studio

Sorry for bad title, but. What I want to achieve is this.

```
private void updateImage(int number) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img0);
}
```

..where the 0 in img0 is actually the parameter *number*.

The JavaScript way would be `R.drawable['img' + number]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A no brainer approach could be as simple as to use array of integer. Put all the resourceId in an array, and simply call the array element by their indices.

```
int[] resIds = new int[] {
      R.drawable.img0,
      R.drawable.img1,
      R.drawable.img2,
      R.drawable.img3
}

private void updateImage(int number) {
      imageView.setImageResource(resIds[number]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Reflections

```
for(Field field : R.drawable.getClass().getFields()) {
     if(field.getName().equals("img" + number)) {
          imageView.setImageResource(field.get(R.drawable));
     }
}
```

Comment: `Non-static method getClass() cannot be referenced from a static context`